# Compute gradients in parallel

Tags: gradient-descent, loss-function, batch-normalization

Here is part of my code:

```
class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 1,  bias=False)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(1, 2,  bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.linear1(x)
        y_pred = self.linear2(z)

        return y_pred, z

model = SimpleNet().cuda()

for epoch in range(1):
    model.train()
    for i, dt in enumerate(data.trn_dl):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(dt[0])

        loss2 = 0
        for j in range(0,len(output[0])):            
            l1 = torch.autograd.grad(output[0][j][0], output[1], create_graph=True)[0][j]
            l2 = torch.autograd.grad(output[0][j][1], output[1], create_graph=True)[0][j]
            loss2 = loss2 + abs(torch.sqrt(l1**2+l2**2)-1)
        loss1 = F.mse_loss(output[0], dt[1])
        loss = loss1+loss2 
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    if epoch%100==0:
        print(loss1,loss2,loss)
```

So I need the gradient of the output layer with respect to some node (this is a simple example, the real one has more layers in between), which I calculate using `torch.autograd.grad(output[0][j][0], output[1], create_graph=True)[0][j]`. However the way I do it now requires that for loop, over each element of the batch which is very slow. Is there a way to take this gradient all at once for a batch? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [developers docs for torch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) specify that the arguments can be tensors, so you can just pass the tensors directly, but you need to reshape your output so that j is the last index. First, rewrite your code so that j is the last index and in your for-loop you have

```
l1 = torch.autograd.grad(output[0][0][j], ...)
```

And then drop the for-loop and remove the j-indices.

Comment: So I tried this: `outp = torch.t(output[0])                                                                           l1 = torch.autograd.grad(outp[0], output[1], create_graph=True)[0]` But I still get the `grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs` error unless I use the loop over j. How exactly should I do what you suggested?